# Handle Field Level Access on MVC Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I came across and programming issue in my MVC app where I need to provide field-level security for some of my forms.  So I need to display or hide fields on the form, based on the user's permissions.  Additionally, I need to validate on post to see if the user can edit a field or add a new record.

The only solution I could come up with, was creating a HTML helper for the form and some code to walk over the fields posted to see if the user has permissions, but it doesn't seem right.  How would you handle something like this?  Maybe I am asking the wrong question, but there doesn't seem to be any real examples out there to look at.

How might you go about solving something like this?

Comment: This question is six years old and someone took the time to downvote it.  It is even closed, so not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Do not render fields for which the user doesn't have permission.  The easiest way I can think of to do this is to use a partial view for those fields that require special permissions.

Remember, if you are accepting form data from the user, you still have to validate that data on the server, even for those fields that you aren't rendering, since it's still possible to inject those fields into the page before posting.

**Further Reading**
[MVC4 Model Field Custom Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778587/mvc-4-model-field-custom-authorization)
[Don’t Do Role-Based Authorization Checks; Do Activity-Based Checks](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/)
[Disable some fields based on a user's permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965086)